# How to make the JTextArea fill width and buttonsContainer fill height?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, jtextarea

[image: capture.PNG]

I've tried to use `GridBagLayout`. It makes the `JTextArea` parent container occupy a big width, but the text area itself didn't fill the width. Why?

And I hope the first button is close to the top and the second button is close to the bottom. How can I implement it?

Could you please advise how to correct my code?

The following code is all code for the demo.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;


public class Demo extends JFrame {

    public Demo() throws HeadlessException {
        add(new MainPanel());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class MainPanel extends JPanel {
        private final InputComponent inputComponent = new InputComponent();
        private final ButtonsContainer buttons = new ButtonsContainer();

        public MainPanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 100));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

            add(inputComponent,
                    buildConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, GridConstraints.FILL_BOTH, 1.0, 1.0));
            add(buttons,
                    buildConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, GridConstraints.FILL_BOTH, 0.0, 1.0));
        }
    }

    class InputComponent extends JComponent {

        private final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

        public InputComponent() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }

    class ButtonsContainer extends JComponent {
        private final JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        private final JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");

        public ButtonsContainer() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(button1, buildConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, 1.0, 0.0));
            add(button2, buildConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, 1.0, 0.0));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            final Demo demo = new Demo();
        });
    }

    private GridBagConstraints buildConstraints(
            int x,
            int y,
            int gWidth,
            int gHeight,
            int fill,
            double weightX,
            double weightY
    ) {
        final GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = x;
        constraints.gridy = y;
        constraints.gridwidth = gWidth;
        constraints.gridheight = gHeight;
        constraints.fill = fill;
        constraints.weightx = weightX;
        constraints.weighty = weightY;
        return constraints;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Original Answer

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

Don't use a GUI builder.  You wind up learning the idiosyncracies of the GUI builder, and not learning Java Swing.

I created the following GUI using a `JFrame`, a main `JPanel`, and a button `JPanel`.  If you maximize the GUI, you'll see that the `JTextArea` expands and the `JButtons` stay towards the top and bottom.

[image]

Don't extend Swing components, or any other Java class, unless you want to override one or more of the class methods.  Use composition over inheritance.

You can use multiple simple `JPanels` to create a complex GUI.  The `GridBagLayout` has its uses, like creating a form.  But all that was needed was multiple `BorderLayouts`.

Don't make Swing components class fields unless you need to access the field instance from more than one method.

Organize your code so it reads like an essay, with the most important code towards the top and the more detailed code towards the bottom.  Ideally, the reader of your code will never have to page up to find out something.  No, the compiler doesn't care about the order of the methods.  But human readers sure do.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ExampleBorerLayoutGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new ExampleBorerLayoutGUI();
        });
    }
    
    public ExampleBorerLayoutGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 40);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        panel.add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        panel.add(button2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        return panel;
    }

}
```

### Edited to Add

Here's the GUI with three `JButtons`.  You didn't say whether you wanted the third button on the top or the bottom.  I chose the top.

[image]

I chose a [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for the upper button `JPanel`.  It's easy to add more `JButtons` to a `GridLayout`.

Here's the modified complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ExampleBorderLayoutGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new ExampleBorderLayoutGUI();
        });
    }
    
    public ExampleBorderLayoutGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example Border Layout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 40);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        
        panel.add(createUpperButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(createLowerButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createUpperButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        panel.add(button1);
        
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        panel.add(button2);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createLowerButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Button 3");
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please advise how to implement the same effect when there are 3 buttons to add in east buttons panel? still using BorderLayout and making the second button at Centre will result in the second button occupy more height. Thanks

Comment: @ildvzg68472: See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! so it's necessary to evaluate first. is there any LayoutManager which works like "justify-content: space-between" in flex in CSS where developer just need add new elements and it will respect element's preferred size and help arrange with the same space among them? Thanks

Comment: @ildvzg68472: Swing is not CSS.  You have to approach creating a GUI in a totally different manner.  Generally, you do what I did.  1) Design the entire GUI.  2) Break the GUI down into as many `JPanels` as you need.  3) Code each `JPanel`.

Answer (score -1):

You can auto-generate the right UI code if you use Eclipse IDE's Window Builder:
https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

It is far easier to design your application that way. Set this up on your IDE and let it do the heavy lifting for you. If you wish to incorporate dynamic resizing of your UI elements, design the code to be [responsive.](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/02/responsive-uis-with-eclipse-and-swt.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).